# CNN + LSTM model for images performs poorly on validation data set

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, lstm, convolutional-neural-network, overfitting

My training and loss curves look like below and yes, similar graphs have received comments like "Classic overfitting" and I get it.

[image: Accuracy and loss plot]

My model looks like below,

```
input_shape_0 = keras.Input(shape=(3,100, 100, 1), name="img3")

model = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Conv2D(8, 3, activation="relu"))(input_shape_0)
model = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.3))(model)
model = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(2))(model)

model = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Conv2D(16, 3, activation="relu"))(model)
model = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(2))(model)

model = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu"))(model)
model = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(2))(model)

model = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.3))(model)
model = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Flatten())(model)
model = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.4))(model)

model = LSTM(16, kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.007))(model)

# model = Dense(100, activation="relu")(model)
# model = Dense(200, activation="relu",kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.001))(model)
model = Dense(60, activation="relu")(model)
# model = Flatten()(model)

model = Dropout(0.15)(model)
out = Dense(30, activation='softmax')(model)

model = keras.Model(inputs=input_shape_0, outputs = out, name="mergedModel")

def get_lr_metric(optimizer):
    def lr(y_true, y_pred):
        return optimizer.lr
    return lr

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop()
lr_metric = get_lr_metric(opt)
# merged.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
                 optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
                optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy',lr_metric])
model.summary()
```

In the above model building code, please consider the commented lines as some of the approaches I have tried so far.

I have followed the suggestions given as answers and comments to this kind of question and none seems to be working for me. Maybe I am missing something really important?

Things that I have tried:

Dropouts at different places and different amounts.
Played with inclusion and expulsion of dense layers and their number of units.
Number of units on the LSTM layer was tried with different values (started from as low as 1 and now at 16, I have the best performance.)
Came across weight regularization techniques and tried to implement them as shown in the code above and so tried to put it at different layers ( I need to know what is the technique in which I need to use it instead of simple trial and error - this is what I did and it seems wrong)
Implemented learning rate scheduler using which I reduce the learning rate as the epochs progress after a certain number of epochs.
Tried two LSTM layers with the first one having return_sequences = true.
After all these, I still cannot overcome the overfitting problem. My data set is properly shuffled and divided in a train/val ratio of 80/20.

Data augmentation is one more thing that I found commonly suggested which I am yet to try, but I want to see if I am making some mistake so far which I can correct it and avoid diving into data augmentation steps for now. My data set has the below sizes:

```
Training images: 6780
Validation images: 1484
```

he numbers shown are samples and each sample will have 3 images. So basically, I input 3 mages at once as one sample to my time-distributed `CNN` which is then followed by other layers as shown in the model description. Following that, my training images are 6780 * 3 and my Validation images are 1484 * 3. Each image is 100 * 100 and is on channel 1.

I am using `RMS prop` as the optimizer which performed better than `adam` as per my testing

Answer (score 1):

I am tempted to answer 'Classic Overfitting'. I am afraid the first cause would be lack of data. You can try to reduce model size / add regularisation, this will reduce the difference in error between train and test, but it is unlikely to increase the test performance significantly.

Answer (score -1):

I know it is an old thread but I am facing a similar problem. Did you find out what was the issue with your model?

P.S.: I know this field is supposed to post answers but I didn't find another place to post.